# Problema ao usar Gson no Wildfly

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, gson

Estou tentando usar o GSON em um projeto Maven EJB mas da o seguinte erro:

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`

Quando testo na classe *main* sem subir o servidor a *lib* funciona normalmente.

Alguém já teve um problema parecido?

Answer (score 0):

No caso da aplicação Web JSP / Servlet, basta copiar o JAR do GSon na pasta / WEB-INF / lib. Se for um projeto utilizando maven adicione

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

ao pom.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

dependendo da sua ide, vc precisa fazer um clean e um re-build no projeto